# C# - ASP.NET - DropDownList in GridView - SelectedValue error

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a gridview which looks like this:
[image: viewing-mode Gridview]

And for my column "ms_resp_team" I use a dropdownlist to allow the user to choose a certain team. However when I enter in edit mode, I can't figure out how to set the selectedValue of the dropdownlist to the actual value and not to the first value of the datasource that fills the dropdownlist!

See here:
[image: fail editing mode]

Can some1 help me with this? When I set the property SelectedValue (to the DDL) that webpage is going berzerk by showing an error!

Comment: Could you provide the error text, stacktrace, etc as well?

Comment: Are you trying to reference the ItemTemplate from the EditTemplate?  I don't believe that will work (but I could be wrong).  I had to work with ViewState to solve this problem (but perhaps there is a better solution).

Comment: what is your **error** ?

Answer (score 0):

The client side syntax for the DropDownList SelectedValue is

```
SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ValueColumnName")'
```

i.e.

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddl" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ValueColumnName")'  DataSource="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="TextColumnName" DataValueField="ValueColumnName" />
```

Make sure you are using different quotes otherwise the interpreter will get confused. Single quotes for the control parameter value and double quotes for the Bind parameter value.

The DateValueField parameter must also be set otherwise you will get the following error:

> 'ddl' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.